# Can you say I don't and can't do anything

Tags: grammar

eg. They don't have to do chores and can't do chores. Can I merge these and say they don't and can't do chores?

Comment: 'They don't do the chores' is not the same as 'They don't *have to do the chores*'. I wouldn't recommend it, to me it sounds bulky.

Comment: Is there a way of merging these two clauses?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with "They don't and can't do chores."

Comment: The phrase "They don't and can't do the chores" is perfectly fine, but the OP is asking about "**don't have to**" which means doing something is not necessary. E.g. *"I don't have to do the shopping"* can mean that I don't need to buy anything, or that someone else does the shopping. But my doing the shopping is not prohibited. I can do it, if I like.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: If I say "I don't do chores" it can mean "I don't have to do chores" or "chores are not required of me" or any of a number of expressions. It does not necessarily mean one refuses to do them, it just means one's doing of them doesn't happen for whatever reason.

Comment: "I don't have to do chores" (it is not necessary) and "I don't do chores" (a task that I do not perform)  are semantically different. They are *not* identical, they are, at best, related.

Comment: Maybe when analyzed structurally, but not in terms of *actual everyday usage* by native speakers.

Comment: Your examples are inconsistent. Do you want to maintain the 'have to' part? Then you can say "They don't have to and can't do chores"

Comment: @Robusto I think the information expressed by "I don't do chores" vs "I don't have to do chores" is actually quite different. The former says that you don't do it, but doesn't say why, the latter says you aren't required to do it, but doesn't say if you do it or not. Thus, I'd say that you shouldn't just switch one sentence for another.

Comment: Not saying there's not a difference of any kind, only that the shorter version sometimes stands in for the longer and is understood to mean any of a number of possible things. Which I've said before and say again now. And that is my last word on the subject.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with saying

> They don't and can't do chores.

This expression uses the rhetorical device known as **zeugma**. From [Sylvae Rhetorica](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/):

> A general term describing when one part of speech (most often the main verb, but sometimes a noun) governs two or more other parts of a sentence (often in a series).
>   . . .
>   Zeugma comprises several more specialized terms, all of which employ ellipsis and parallelism (among the governed members of the sentence). The zeugma figures are of two types: those in which the governing word is the main verb (in which case these are subsequently categorized according to the position of that governing verb), and those in which the governing word is another part of speech (usually the subject noun).

In this case, you're linking two verbs to the same object. The *do* is elided from the first verb, making it kind of a double-jointed zeugma, in that it links both *don't* and *can't* to the helper verb *do*, and then to the object *chores*.

**EDIT:** To respond to an objection that "don't have to" is not the same as "don't" (a premise that is arguable if not as far-reaching as the objecter wishes to make it out to be) I will note that the zeugma works just as well with the wordier

> They don't have to and can't do chores.

The point is, if I say I "don't do something" it can mean a number of things: that I am not required to do them, refuse to do them, have never had the occasion to do them, or any of a number of things. It's ambiguous, to be sure, but that is how people talk.

Comment: But *don't have to do the chores* is not the same as *don't do the chores*, they are quite different in meaning, as I'm sure you're aware of.

Comment: The question is whether you can say "They don't and can't do chores." In any case, "they don't do chores" is one way of expressing "they don't have to do chores." It doesn't *have* to mean that, but it can. With questions like these it is anybody's guess where the OP's misunderstanding lies.

Comment: No. The question is **They don't have to do chores and can't do chores** If your guess is the  OP believes that "They don't have to do the shopping" is the same as "They must not do the shopping" then you should have first clarified that. And mk_hcc's suggestion is semantically more accurate because it is longer (9 words compare to your 6)

Comment: What? Now you're equating "They don't have to do the shopping" with "They must not do the shopping"? Where do you get that notion? Also, you seem to have extra hostility toward me today. I never said mk_hoc's suggestion wasn't more accurate, only that it was not as [succinct](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/succinct).

Comment: No, I'm not. You were the first to suggest that the OP misunderstood. The negative form of "have to" is often misinterpreted by learners. I do not know if the OP is a native speaker or non, but if he is the latter, then perhaps this explains the *possible* confusion between "must not" and "don't have to".

Comment: I don't know why you're so determined to misread everything I'm saying, but I suppose that is your right. Enjoy.

Comment: Extra hostility toward you today? You make it sound that I constantly hound you. Rubbish, false and untrue.

Comment: This comment exchange is utterly perplexing. I don't understand how "have to do" ever entered the picture. The question never was about "have to do". It was all about "do" all along. Who cares if the OP does or does not "believe 'They don't have to do the shopping' is the same as 'They must not do the shopping'". That is not what their question is about. For all I know they think "to sweep" means "purple cat". Who even cares.

Answer (score 1):

A more succinct sentence construction could be "**They neither have to do chores, nor can they**".

Comment: How is that more succinct?

Comment: There's no repetition of the 'do chores' phrase. I originally had it as 'elegant' but that's too subjective.

Comment: It's not more succinct than "They don't and can't do chores." Six words to your nine, and no comma to break the flow."

Comment: The elephant in the room is that this does not answer the question. It does not so much as *address* it. It barely qualifies for a comment in its current form.

Comment: It's not terribly succinct compare to the original 10 words. I grant @Robusto that. Elegant, although subjective, would have been more accurate.